# Wordpress Transparent Header & Body

Tags: css, wordpress, background, transparent

Working on a Wordpress site that we're putting a Parallax background in, but I'm having a tough time with making the header transparent and perhaps a little opacity in the content.

For example, the header is currently following this style:

```
.header {
  border-top-color:#F09C41;
  border-top-style:solid;
  border-top-width:0;
}
```

using the following doesn't help:

```
.header {
  background:transparent !important;
  border-top-color:#F09C41;
  border-top-style:solid;
  border-top-width:0;
}
```

Similar with the content. You can see the demo site here: http://tinyurl.com/nutvfvb

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I thought this one would be easy...but I guess not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `div` titled "main-content" has a white `background-color` to it. So when you add any `transparency` your header appears white. 
You can use:

```
.header {
   background-color:transparent;
}
```

and change the `background-color` of the "main-content" and view it in a browser.

Try this:

```
div.main-content {
background-color:red;
}
```

and your header should appear red.

This is only to show you that the header is transparent when you add:

```
.header {
   background-color:transparent;
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

use

`.header {
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
}`

Comment: because they are "main-content" behind header with white background

Comment: I have that set to transparent as well: .main-content {
 background-color: transparent;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 1000px;
}

Comment: In chrome press f12 to see the console and see what styles are being applied. Apparently there is another style 'background: #FFF' this on your style

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work because you have set `background-color` property of `.main-content` div to white too.